# Calling a CPP function from C with no header file

Tags: c++, c

I don't get it, how is the 'connection' made if there is no .h file.

Here is the code:

file main.c:

```
void Run( void ) ;
int main(void)
{
    Run() ;
}
```

file: run.cpp:

```
static MyClass gMyClassInstance;
extern "C" {
    void Run( void )
    {
       gMyClassInstance->Run();
    }

}
```

Searched for `Run` in the entire project, never appears again and not in any .h file. How does it do it?

Comment: Header files typically contains the function *declarations*. Not the functions themselves. Since you provide your own declaration of `Run` in your `main.c` file it's okay.

Comment: how does it know to find the definition of it? is it the compiler , linker?

Comment: The linker searches all the component object modules/files for the definition of `Run` when it builds the main program.

Comment: I feel I've been lied all my life, thanks

Comment: The definition is in the object files or libraries you link with.

Comment: `#include` is very simple - preprocessor literally reads the file and copies and pastes its content where include directive was. If you moved `void Run( void ) ;` to header file and included it, the effect would be the same as you have now. It's linker's job to find matching definition to each declaration (although compiler often does it if both are found in the same file).

Comment: This seems like a good time to learn about the concept of [*translation units*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming)). In short, a translation unit is a single source file with all included header files. This is the unit that the compiler deals with. The compiler then creates an object file (which represents the translation unit), which the linker uses (together with libraries) to create the executable program.

Comment: why would it need to be in a header file, what difference would this make?

Comment: so the caller must see a declaration, but the definition can be anywhere I want?

Comment: @schantischul Anywhere the linker can see it, but yes, pretty much anywhere. Compiler only requires function declaration.

Comment: "So the caller must see a declaration, but the definition can be anywhere I want?" Basically, yes. :) As long as "anywhere [you] want" is something that is passed to the linker.

Comment: The "connection" is `extern "C" {`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`.h` files are used to avoid duplicating the declarations from `.c/.cpp` file to `.c/.cpp` file (*declarations* are required by the compiler when the functions are not *defined* locally).

In your example, there is a single declaration `void Run( void );`, directly in `main.c` rather than in a separate `.h`, and this is enough for the compiler. The connection with the `Run` function defined in `run.cpp` will be made by the linker (as an entry point named `_Run`).

*Header files are by no means mandated in C/C++ programming.*

Answer (score 3):

In C and C++, each .cpp or .c file is compiled as an individual translation unit. There are three phases in the process that are relevant here: Preprocessing, compilation, and linking.

During preprocessing, `#include` command is interpreted to copy and paste the contents of the header file at that point. Each preprocessed file is a text file, and is still valid C or C++. Your compiler probably allows you to preprocess a file and observe the result file, if you want to find out more about the process.

Preprocessed files are then compiled separately. From the viewpoint of the compiler, it doesn't matter where the function declaration was initially, because it works on the preprocessed files. You could take the preprocessed file, add it to your project as .cpp file, and it would still compile.

Because the files are compiled separately, it is common to call functions that are defined in a different translation unit. A function declaration simply tells the compiler that the function will be found somewhere in the program.

After every translation unit has been compiled, the linker processes them to make a final program. This includes finding each function definition, and making the connection with each function call. If the definition is not found, there will be an error.